# Recursive function to calculate time of a hierarchy

Tags: c#, recursion, foreach

I'm having problem with a recursive function for calculating the time of an hierarchy. Every item in the hierarchy have list of its subordinates and what I'll like to do is getting the time sum of all the step below when calling the function. The problem is that I have a time driver that the time should be multiplied by. Say for instance that the last step in the hierarchy have the time driver 2 and the step above it the time driver 4, the third step from the bottom should then get the time for 4 of those steps under which each one contains 2  of the first step. Hope you get the idea.

```
    public double getIdealTime(double sum, bool first)
    {
        if (first)
        {
            sum += this.idealTime;
            first = false;
        }

        else
        {
            sum += this.idealTime * this.timeDriverNumber;

        }


        foreach (var prodel in this.subordinates)
        {
            sum = prodel.getIdealTime(sum, first);

        }

        return sum;
    }
```

The "first" true and false is just a solution to not get the time of all the steps (the time x the time drivers) for the actual step but for only one of that instance.

The problem is that the function doesn't give me the right output value. I'm not sure why, but it feels like the function goes "top to bottom" instead of "bottom to top". That is, since one usually only set the time for the last items and then calculate the times using the subordinates and its subordinates, it doesn't multiplicate with any other timedriver than the last one.

An example:

```
Step 1
  step 2 time driver 8
    Step 2.1 = 3s time driver 4
    Step 2.2 = 4s time driver 3
```

Should for step 1 generate (4*3 + 3*4) * 8 =  192 seconds but gives me 24 seconds since it doesn't multiply with step twos timedriver of 8. Step 2 gives me 24 seconds as it should since it should give me the time for one of the step 2 only.

**Edit: I've tried to work out a working example but I can't simplify the code to build around it enough to get something I could publish here. I'd still really appreciate some help though!**

Comment: Whats the exact problem? are you getting an error or are results not as expected? (if so do you have examples of inputs/outputs)

Comment: The problem is that I don't get the desired output value. I'll update the first post with some information!

Comment: If i've understood it right then don't you just need to move the `timedrivernumber` after the method call? so `return sum * driverNumber`

Comment: Thanks, that kind of work! It still gives me the problem of multiplying with the timedriver for the actual element I'm getting the time for though, and not only for one instance of it. Getting around it by multiplying the result of the function by the first time driver isn't a very good solution either, since the time driver could be set to zero. Also, having to divide every time doesn't seem like a very robust way of coding.

Comment: if your over by an ammount every time then its probably because of the  if first time check needed on the return

Comment: No sorry, for some reason it still wont work properly now that I test with the same values as before. It seems like it always gives me exactly double the value it should, appart from the problem that it still counts the time driver for the step I'm calling from.

Comment: If your still stuck, I could probably see if i have time later to take a look at it if you could modify your code above to be a complete working example, (example inputs and outputs as well as values for all variables)

Comment: Sayse, that'd be deeply appreciated!